# Managing mailman configuration with augeas

Tags: mailman, augeas

I want to create an augeas lens to modify mailman lists. The lists are stored in a binary file which can be exported to a plaintext file using `config_list -o /tmp/config my_list` and reimported by replacing `-o` by `-i`.

The goal is to build an augeas tree like this:

```
/mailman/my_list/real_name = "my mailman list"
/mailman/my_list/description = "This is my first list"
...
/mailman/another_list/real_name = "my other list"
/mailman/another_list/description = "This is just another list"
...
```

Is is possible to build a lens which produces the given tree by using the mailman commands `list_lists` and `config_list`?

Thanks,
krissi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Augeas cannot work directly with input/output commands. However, you could use bindings with the `aug_store` and `aug_retrieve` API calls in Augeas 1.0.0 to manipulate the strings in memory.

As an example, you might be interested in [`auggrep`](https://github.com/raphink/augeas-sandbox#auggrep), a small bash utility using Augeas to parse logs (kind of a proof of concept thus far).